# Why are some nouns autocapitalized when writing answers or comments?

Tags: discussion, comments

When I write a comment or answer, some of the nouns I type are autocapitalized as soon as I type the blank closing the word. Why is that? Any way to Switch it off?

Since the language used is English, uppercase words are wrong most of the time. So I have to go back and Change the upper- into the lowercase letter.

As you possibly recognize, my native language is not English. It is German, and in German nouns *are* written capitalized all the time. So maybe the site recogizes (from user-Agent specs or IP localization) that I am from Germany and therefore capitalizes? Doesn't Sound resonable. (The upper "S" in "Sound" just typed was automatically changed by the site!)

Comment: Stack Overflow doesn't do that. Your browser or operating system does this.

Comment: This sounds like the auto-correct feature in your browser thinking you're typing German text. Not sure why it wouldn't show up on any web site

Comment: Ok, I'm convinced. I just don't see why this gets so many downvotes - I had no idea that this would be a browser Thing. Sorry. :-(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a behavior that comes from Stack Overflow's website. Instead it is likely your browser or device causing the issue.

Comment: But why have I never seen this behaviour at any other web site?  Something Special about stackoverflows <textarea> elements?

Comment: Perhaps you just have not been observant on other sites. The behavior you describe has nothing to do with anything site specific. This is not the proper place to try to debug what your browser/device is doing.